# Raspberry Pi connection closed by host problem

Tags: raspbian, ssh, noobs

I am not able to ssh to raspberry pi after 2-3 hours. This all started after installing Plex Server on it but not sure if this is a mere conincidence. At first, I got "connection reset by peer" error after typing "ssh user@ip" on the terminal. Assuming, it was a server load problem (hence crashing), I swapped my sdcard from raspberry pi 2 model b+ to raspberry pi 3 after update/upgrade. Now I get "Connection closed by  port 22" when i tried to ssh. Tried many computers. All the other non ssh connections also don't work. After every restart it works normally for a few hours. I can successfully ping but can't connect. How I start to debug this issue? Where to look for trouble? How to see server logs? I am running latest version of Raspbian on it. Pi is powered through usb hub. It is connected to wireless network. I wasn't able to ping with raspberry pi 2 model b+ version but after swapping cards to raspberry pi 3, ping works when SSH fails. There is no firewall. It had been working fine with this kinda setup for months. I understand there is some non trivial issue and wondering how to check server logs for trouble. 
Please advise.

Comment: If you have physical access to the Pi, try hooking up a keyboard / monitor and check directly if the Pi is working, run `less /var/log/syslog` and see if any errors have been logged

Answer (score 1):

A USB hub powered or otherwise is not able to supply enough power to the Pi. This is likely the cause of your issues. Keep the USB hub for powering the WiFi dongle, and get a proper 5v 2A powersupply.

Comment: But if it was working fine for months why would it give problems now? I will power it through adapter if you recommend that. Thanks for your feedback, I will debug it.

Comment: It may well work fine for a time (or you may not notice the problem), but that does mean it is recommended or appropriate. It is a bit like saying the AC worked last summer - why doesn't it not work now. Also, if you look around this site most issues such as you describe can be directly attributed to power issues, and until you remove that as a cause you are just wasting time.

Comment: I understand. I will change it to power adapter.